# In Allure reports, how to provide distinct severity to each data set in parameterized test in TestNG?

Tags: java, testng, allure

I know we can mention severity for a test for allure report as below:

```
@Severity(SeverityLevel.CRITICAL)
@Test(dataProvider = "TH_DataProvider",enabled=true)
public void M01_createRelease(String sNo, String te....)
```

But the problem with above configuration is that for all the test data combinations, the SeverityLevel is set to CRITICAL. But ideally the SeverityLevel will vary for each dataset provided by the data provider. Is it possible to mention distinct SeverityLevel for each data set provided by the TestNG data provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always set Severity programmatically:

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.Allure;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.events.TestCaseEvent;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.SeverityLevel;
import ru.yandex.qatools.allure.model.TestCaseResult;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertTrue;
import static ru.yandex.qatools.allure.AllureUtils.createSeverityLabel;

public class ParameterizedTestngTest {

    @DataProvider(name = "TH_DataProvider")
    public static Object[][] dataProvider() {
        return new Object[][] {{"Minor", "Test data 1"}, {"Major", "Test data 2"}, {"Blocker", "Test data 3"}};
    }

    // @Severity(SeverityLevel.TRIVIAL) // overwriting annotation is also possible, please uncomment code in event class
    @Test(dataProvider = "TH_DataProvider", enabled = true)
    public void M01_createRelease(String sNo, String te) {
        SeverityLevel severity = SeverityLevel.TRIVIAL;

        // overwriting default severity
        if (sNo.equals("Minor")) {
            severity = SeverityLevel.MINOR;
        } else if (sNo.equals("Blocker")) {
            severity = SeverityLevel.BLOCKER;
        }
        Allure.LIFECYCLE.fire(new SetSeverityEvent(severity));

        // test
        assertTrue(true);
    }

    public static class SetSeverityEvent implements TestCaseEvent{

        private SeverityLevel severity;

        public SetSeverityEvent(SeverityLevel severity) {
            this.severity = severity;
        }

        @Override
        public void process(TestCaseResult context) {
            context.withSeverity(severity);

            // you can additionally remove severity label im case you use @Severity annotation as your default severity
//            context.setLabels(Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(context.getLabels(), new Predicate<Label>() {
//                @Override
//                public boolean apply(Label label) {
//                    return !label.getName().equals(LabelName.SEVERITY);
//                }
//            })));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks perfect. Will try it out today.